# Libvlcsharp will get stuck playing specific videos on any platform

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp, vlc-android

Playing the following video will get stuck. On any platform, I have tried WinForm, WPF, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios
For the following two videos, I get stuck in xamarin.forms, Android and IOS, and the playback is not smooth, but there is no problem playing them with the browser. I don't know why?

https://bj.bcebos.com/kpy-organizations/U3017318/videos/2021091617080192065864213581.mp4
https://bj.bcebos.com/kpy-organizations/U12760068/videos/2021083110332897820349837654.mp4

Comment: Do they play in VLC itself? A good place to start would be to go to Messages and turn that up to Debug, then save that log. It will help folks who are troubleshooting. If it struggles to play in VLC itself, then it is likely not a LibVLCSharp issue.

Comment: https://github.com/bbhxwl/TestLibVlcBug

Comment: It can't be played in c# and it can be played normally by using VLC client. I think although this may be a coding problem, there are ways to solve it. Or is there a bug in libvlcsharp?

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/bbhxwl/TestLibVlcBug/blob/85b293f9a2d20c17057fcae6c7709d5f4b07045c/TestLibVlcBug/TestLibVlcBug/MainPage.xaml.cs#L25) it appears you are loading directly off of the network. When you indicated that the VLC client is able to play it normally, did you test it both a) on the same platform and b) by loading the network stream as your code does rather than as a local file? (I've seen some differences in stream vs. file playing in the past)

Answer (score 0):

```
main error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 4929000, buffering 100000, bound 3000000)
main error: Could not convert timestamp 64957762948 for faad
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (jitter of 19946 ms ignored)
main error: Timestamp conversion failed for 10733334: no reference clock
main error: Could not get display date for timestamp 0
```

Lots of those. I don't know how you encoded your video, but you probably did something wrong.

Comment: I just read this comment. I wonder if you can't play such a video? However, you can play the video normally by using the MediaElement in the xamarin community toolkit.